# Django flake8 I001 isort found an import in the wrong position

Tags: python, django, flake8

Подскажите, что может быть не так.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    path(
        'redoc/',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='redoc.html'),
        name='redoc'
    ),
]
```

`/urls.py:2:1: I001 isort found an import in the wrong position`

`/urls.py:3:1: I005 isort found an unexpected missing import`

Comment: о, это вроде старый баг был такой у isort. точнее фича. попробуйте импортируемые модули расставить в алфавитном порядке (поменяйте во втором импорте `path` и `include` местами)

Comment: Класс, спасибо, друг, не догадался